# How to list Management Certificate In windows azure using REST Api

Tags: azure

I am tring to list all the management certificates in a windows azure subcription. And I tried with the following code. But it gives me an exception. And I could find that `response` is null and the exception message is `"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."`

Please help me with this. [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154105.aspx) doesn't provide an example for this :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class ManagemenCertificateViewer
{
    public static void Runme()
    {
        string msVersion = "2012-03-01";
        string subscriptionId = "I used the subscription Id here";
        try
        {
            ListManagementCertificates(subscriptionId, msVersion);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void ListManagementCertificates(string subscriptionId, string version)
    {
        string uriFormat = "https://management.core.windows.net/{0}/certificates";
        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(uriFormat, subscriptionId));

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", version);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";

        XDocument responseBody = null;
        HttpStatusCode statusCode;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            // GetResponse throws a WebException for 400 and 500 status codes
            response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        }
        statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        if (response.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseBody = XDocument.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        response.Close();
        if (statusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            XNamespace wa = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure";
            XElement storageServices = responseBody.Element(wa + "SubscriptionCertificates");
            int mngmntCertificateCount = 0;
            foreach (XElement storageService in storageServices.Elements(wa + "SubscriptionCertificate"))
            {
                string publicKey = storageService.Element(wa + "SubscriptionCertificatePublicKey").Value;
                string thumbprint = storageService.Element(wa + "SubscriptionCertificateThumbprint").Value;
                string certificateData = storageService.Element(wa + "SubscriptionCertificateData").Value;
                string timeCreated = storageService.Element(wa + "TimeCreated").Value;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Certificate[{0}]{1}  SubscriptionCertificatePublicKey: {2}{1}  SubscriptionCertificateThumbprint: {3}{1} certificateData{4}{1} timeCreated{5}{1}",
                    mngmntCertificateCount++, Environment.NewLine, publicKey, thumbprint, certificateData, timeCreated);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("List Management certificates returned an error:");
            Console.WriteLine("Status Code: {0} ({1}):{2}{3}",
                (int)statusCode, statusCode, Environment.NewLine,
                responseBody.ToString(SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces));
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 error means something wrong with your management certificate used to authenticate your Service Management API requests. I don't see you attaching a management certificate along with your request in your code. You may find this link useful for authenticating service management API requests: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782.

HTH.

Comment: I had that problem in my mind :) We need to authenticate our self. That's what you are saying right? So always we have to keep a seperate management certificate with us for the use of API.
I'll try with that
Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Basically it's a catch 22 situation :) In order to manage management certificates, you need to have at least one management certificate. One thing you could do is make use of Publish Settings File for that 1st certificate and then use that for further operations on management certificates.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks it's working as I expected. I just add the following line and the Method 'GetCertificate(arg1)'

```
request.ClientCertificates.Add(GetCertificate(certThumbprint));
```

One more thing, in [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154105.aspx) help guide there's a tag in respond body called

```
<TimeCreated>time-created</TimeCreated>
```

But the api responds not the TimeCreated its just created.

```
<Created> ..... </Created>
```